# C read bmp pixels into 2d array

Tags: c, arrays, bmp

I've got the header and info header. the first pixel reads ok with the following code.

```
// The BMPHEADER structure.
typedef struct {
byte        sigB;
byte        sigM;
int32_t     fileSize;
int16_t     resv1;
int16_t     resv2;
int32_t     pixelOffset;
} tBmpHeader;

// The BMPINFOHEADER structure.
typedef struct {
int32_t     size;
int32_t     width;
int32_t     height;
int16_t     colorPlanes;
int16_t     bitsPerPixel;
byte        zeros[24];
} tBmpInfoHeader;

typedef uint8_t byte;

typedef struct {
byte blue;
byte green;
byte red;
} tPixel;

// A BMP image consists of the BMPHEADER and BMPINFOHEADER structures, and the 2D pixel array.
typedef struct {
tBmpHeader      header;
tBmpInfoHeader  infoHeader;
tPixel          **pixel;
} tBmp;

tPixel **BmpPixelAlloc(int pWidth, int pHeight)
{
    tPixel **pixels = (tPixel **)malloc (pHeight * sizeof(tPixel *));
    for (int row = 0; row < pHeight; ++row)
    {
        pixels[row] = (tPixel *)malloc(pWidth * sizeof(tPixel));
    }

    return pixels;
}

tError BmpRead(char *pFilename, tBmp *pBmp)
{
pBmp->pixel = BmpPixelAlloc(pBmp->infoHeader.width, pBmp->infoHeader.height);

if(FileRead(file, &pBmp->pixel, sizeof(tPixel), 1)!=0)
{ 
    errorCode = ErrorFileRead;
}
}
```

a tutor I was talking to said I should do the following

```
int i = 0;
while(!feof(file))
{
    if(FileRead(file, &pBmp->pixel[i], sizeof(tPixel), 1)!=0)
    { 
    errorCode = ErrorFileRead;
    }
    ++i;
}
```

but this gives me a segmentation fault. if i put a print in the loop it prints a few thousand times before saying segmentation fault. I tried using a double for loop but that wouldn't even compile. I've spent a few hours on google but cant figure it out.

Comment: Why bother? There's already an easy-to-use and easy-to-understand [library](http://easybmp.sourceforge.net/) for this.

Comment: Well, even so, try going through the code in that library. You might learn some stuff.

Comment: Side note: Be aware of structure padding in `tBmpHeader`: the two single bytes might cause a 2 byte hole to align the following `uint32_t` (pack the structure or remove these magic bytes and read them separately)

Comment: @sam yeah i already had to deal with that i ended up reading in that structure in pieces.

Answer (score 0):

never mind i figured it out.

```
for(int i = 0; i < pBmp->infoHeader.height; ++i)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < pBmp->infoHeader.width; ++j)
    {
        if(FileRead(file, &pBmp->pixel[i][j], sizeof(tPixel), 1)!=0)
        { 
            errorCode = ErrorFileRead;
        }
    }
}
```